# Is the sum of two rationals or two irrationals irrational?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, rationality-testing

**1.** I know this statement is false (if I am correct) but how to prove it's false?

> "The sum of two rational numbers is irrational."

**2.** I know this statement is true (if I am correct) but how to prove it's true?

> "The sum of two irrational numbers is irrational"

I used the example $\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3} = 3.14$

But i may need to use proof by contradiction or contaposition.

Comment: How can sum of two rational number be irrational?

Comment: $\frac pq$+$\frac xz$ can never yield an irrational number.

Comment: Exactly....but how to prove it

Comment: @Moishin-I (and others) have given the proof below.

Comment: The sum of two irrational numbers need not be irrational. For example, $\pi + (-\pi)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If two numbers are rational we can express their sum as
$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d}$$
which is equal to $$\frac{ad + bc}{bd}.$$
Hence, rational.

The sum of two irrational numbers may be irrational. Consider $2+\sqrt2$ and $3+\sqrt2$. Both are irrational, and so is their sum $5+2\sqrt2$.

Comment: ad + bc / bd shows that it is always rational. how can it be shown it is not "maybe" irrational...

Comment: Since it is always rational, it can never be irrational. A real number cannot both be rational and irrational. This follows from definition.

Answer (score 1):

For one, it comes directly from the closure of addition on $\mathbb{Q}$, but I don't think that's the answer they would expect.

Let $a = \dfrac{p_1}{q_1}$ and $b = \dfrac{p_2}{q_2}$ be rationals in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $q_1, q_2 \neq 0$:
$$a + b = \dfrac{p_1}{q_1} + \dfrac{p_2}{q_2} = \dfrac{p_1q_2 + p_2q_1}{q_1q_2} \in \mathbb{Q}$$

For the second one, how about $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \sqrt{2}$. A single example is sufficient to prove the claim.

For bonus points, can you prove that $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ is irrational?
(Hint: Contradiction. Suppose it's rational, and use the closure of addition on $\mathbb{Q}$ that was proven.)

Comment: But the statement was "The sum of two irrational numbers **is** irrational", not it **can** be.  That statement is false though, because $(\sqrt2)+(1-\sqrt2)=1$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac pq$+$\frac xz$ $(q,z \neq 0)$(by formula of rational numbers).

=$\frac{pz+qz}{qz}$
,which is again in the form $\frac ab$ so it is bound to be rational and also $qz$ is not equal to $0$.

Sum of irrational may be irrational is true but it is always rational if the sum consists of the irrational number and its negative and then the sum will yield $0$.
Sum of two irrational numbers that you expressed as a decimal is not true and only an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of two irrational numbers is not necessarily irrational.  For example, $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ are two irrational numbers, but their sum is zero ($0$), which in turn is rational.